# Selecting only enabled checkboxes in RadGrid control

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, radgrid

I have a RadGrid control that is displays disabled or enabled checkboxes based on the database values.

I have a radio button "Select All" that needs to check all enabled checkboxes in the grid. However, I am not able to detect if the checkbox is enabled or disabled.

The html code for the checkbox is:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Certified" HeaderText="Certified" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged" 
        Enabled='<%# !bool.Parse(Eval("Certified").ToString()) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

My codebehind is:

```
foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    if (((CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox2")).Enabled != false) ;
    {
        ((CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox2")).Checked = true;
    }
}
```

How can I go about returning only enabled checkboxes in the if statement?

Comment: Where/when is the for each firing in your code behind?

Comment: in rbSelectAll_OnSelectedIndexChanged function

Comment: Silly question, but does this fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have strange logic, and ***if statement is ended with comma***.

```
if (((CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox2")).Enabled != false) ;
```

As the result, they become two separate lines.

```
{
   ((CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox2")).Checked = true;
}
```

### Solution

```
foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    var checkbox = dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox2") as CheckBox;
    if (checkbox.Enabled)
    {
        checkbox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The comma was a typo :-)

Comment: I use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/‎) ; it tells me right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
  columns.Bound(c => c.IsSelected)
 .ClientTemplate("<input <#=IsSelected  ? 'checked'  : '' #>  />")
```